# dumb Q of the day: assigning a string into a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, cpu-word

```
string word = "Hello Boys";
char x[100] = word; // wouldn't work
char x[] = word; //wouldn't work either
```

I rarely work with strings and chars and now it's coming back right at me.

Comment: You shouldn't ever really need to do this. What's your actual problem?

Comment: I'm trying to parse a word (e.x. "Hello Boys;" and get "Hello Boys").

Comment: What kinds of restrictions does the input have? In that case, you could just erase the last character.

Comment: You don't have to move it into a character array if you want to examine it. You can reference `word[i-1]` to get at the `i`-th character.

Comment: This is obtained from an ifstream which points to a text file (a novel). so a part of the function looks like this
    while(inputFile >> word)
    {
        parse word
    }
It all comes down to filtering the string and returns a clear string without the unwanted characters (I have the ascii exclusions)

Comment: @mbratch ok.. how about using strlen for that case?

Comment: Of course you could. I wasn't sure of the extent of the "parsing" you were trying to achieve. If all you want to do is get to the last character, then it's `word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0'`.

Comment: but strlen is for character array.. nevermind.. string also has .length function THANKS

Answer (score 0):

To copy a string to a character array, you can use `strcpy`.

Example (uncompiled):

```
strcpy (x, word.c_str());
```

All the usual caveats about using `strcpy` apply; notably, it is up to you, the caller, to ensure that `x` is big enough to hold the contents of `word`.